# How to match version of a command using bash "=~"?

Tags: bash, pcre, posix-ere

```
luajit -v
LuaJIT 2.1.0-beta3 -- Copyright (C) 2005-2017 Mike Pall. http://luajit.org/
```

I want to *negate* match the version part, and got `LUAJIT_VERSION="2.1.0-beta3"` at the beginning of bash script. I use:

```
if ! [[ "$(luajit -v)" =~ LuaJIT\s+"$LUAJIT_VERSION".* ]]; then
#rest of code
```

But it seems not working **whether** I put `$LUAJIT_VERSION` between `""` **or not**:

> Any part of the pattern may be quoted to force the quoted portion to be matched as a string ... If the pattern is stored in a shell variable, quoting the variable expansion forces the entire pattern to be matched as a string.

[Bash docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Conditional-Constructs)

Can you tell me what's the correct way to do this task?

Comment: I don't think you can use `\s` in Bash regular expressions.

Comment: @BenjaminW. But ain't it extended regex? `An additional binary operator, ‘=~’, is available, with the same precedence as ‘==’ and ‘!=’. When it is used, the string to the right of the operator is considered an extended regular expression and matched accordingly`

Comment: Try to use `[[:blank:]]` instead of `\s`

Comment: Yes, but `\s` is not part of ERE. You can use the character class `[[:blank:]]` instead. For a minimal POC: try `[[ ' ' =~ \s ]] || echo "no match"`

Comment: `\s` is more accurately described as a Perl-Compatible Regular Expression (PCRE); it is not a POSIX extended regular expression.

Comment: Thanks. can you write an answer so I mark this question as solved?

Comment: (Even if `\s` were supported, you would need to use `LuaJIT\\s"$LUAJIT_VERISON".*`, so that the literal pair `\s` was part of the regular expression.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\s` is not a recognized character class in `bash`; you need to use `[[:blank:]]` instead:

```
if ! [[ "$(luajit -v)" =~ LuaJIT[[:blank:]]+"$LUAJIT_VERSION" ]]; then
```

(The trailing `.*` isn't necessary, since regular expressions aren't anchored to the start or end of the string.)

---

However, it's not clear your regular expression needs to be that general. It looks like you can use a single, literal space

```
if ! [[ "$(luajit -v)" =~ LuaJIT\ "$LUAJIT_VERSION" ]];
```

or simply use pattern matching:

```
if [[ "$(luajit -v)" != LuaJIT\ "$LUAJIT_VERSION"* ]];
```